# Functional Analysis Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X=C^{1}[0, 1]$. For each of $f\in X$, define  $$p_1(f):=  \sup\{{|f(t)|:t\in [0, 1]}\}$$
$$p_2(f):=  \sup\{{|f'(t)|:t\in [0, 1]}\}$$
$$p_3(f):=p_1(f)+p_2(f)$$
I know that $(X, p_1 ), (X, p_2 )$ are not Banach spaces. Can I claim that $p_3(f)$ is also not a Banach space since each one is not a Banach space? Please help me as I am self studying functional analysis.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Why do you have 'denumerable basis' in the title?

Answer (score 0):

Under $p_3$, $X$ is a Banach space: let $\{f_n\}$ be  a Cauchy sequence. Note that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy under $p_1$ and $p_2$.  By completeness of $C[0,1]$, the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to some continuous function $f$. Similarly, $\{f'_n\}$ converges uniformly to some continuous function $g$. Now, by letting $n \to \infty$ in the equation $f_n(x)=f_n(0)+\int_0^{x} f'_n(t)\, dt$ we get $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x} g(t) \, dt$. This implies that $f$ is differentiable and $g=f'$. It now follows from definition that $p_3(f_n -f) \to 0$.

Comment: Sir could you please explain to me why you have taken $f_n(x)=f_n(0)+\int_0^xf'_n(t)dt$?

Comment: @Ziya To show that $\{f_n\}$ converges w.r.t. $p_3$ you have to find a function $h$ such that $f_n \to h$ uniformly and $f'_n \to h'$  uniformly. The limits of $f_n $ and $f'_n $ have to be related (the derivative of the first limit being the second limit). To prove the relation $g=f'$ I have used the fundamental theorem of calculus writing $f_n(x)$ as $f_n(0)+\int_0^{x}f'_n(t)\, dt$. Taking limits in this equation gives the desired connection between $f$ and $g$.